# Forwarding host OS USB drives to guest as hard drive in Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: usb, virtualbox, usb-storage, ms-dos

I have DOS 6.22 running in Oracle VirtualBox.

Now to the question; is it possible to forward USB drives on the host OS to the guest OS (DOS) as a hard drive?

So instead of using a disk image, you use a real drive?

Answer (score 0):

> Now to the question; is it possible to forward USB drives on the host
>   OS to the guest OS (DOS) as a hard drive?

It depends.

You cannot simultaneously “share” a physical device between the host OS and the guest OS. But if you have a hard drive you want to designate to be used specifically by the guest OS you can setup a device filter in VirtualBox to make that guest OS aware of the device.

The screenshots are from VirtualBox in Mac OS X, but the general concept should work for any system running VirtualBox. In this case I am using VirtualBox 5.0 but this works in VirtualBox 4.3.x as well.

Basically since USB devices connected to a system running VirtualBox can be used by the system’s host OS as well as the guest OS on VirtualBox, VirtualBox has a “device filter” setup to allow you to select which USB devices should be used by the VirtualBox guest OS instead of the main system’s host OS.

First, shut down the virtual machine. Make sure the USB drive is plugged in an powered up so the host OS can recognize it. Now select the “Settings” for that virtual machine and choose the “Ports” option/tab which should look something like this:

[image]

In that area, select the USB part which should then look like this:

[image]

Make sure “Enable USB Controller” is checked and at least one of the USB controller types is selected. I would defer to “USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller” for now.

With that done you see that little icon that looks like a USB plug with a plus (`+`) over it? Click on that and select the USB drive from that menu. Once selected, it should show up in your list of items under “USB Device Filters.”

Once that’s done, just click “OK” and start up your virtual machine.